# SSRS 5 columns from 3 columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have 3 columns:

```
Date    Type    Item
1/1/2015   A      X
3/2/2015   B      X
1/6/2015   A      Y
3/7/2015   B      Y
```

And I want to show table with:

```
DateA Type DateB Type Item
1/1/2015 A 3/2/2015 B X
1/6/2015 A 3/7/2015 B Y
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How many dates are there? only two?

Comment: more than two, this is only for example

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when type = 'A' then date end) as DateA, 'A' as TypeA,
       max(case when type = 'B' then date end) as DateB, 'B' as TypeB
       item
from t
group by item;
```

Comment: @Carma . . . I'm curious why you unaccepted this answer.  Is it not correct?  (An OP can accept whichever answer s/he wants; I'm curious why this was unaccepted.)